# Is it possible to use methods with new MapperConfiguration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper-5

I got a very simple question...
Is it possible to setup a AutoMapper like this:

```
public IMapper Init()
{
     var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
     {
         cfg = MappingModelsToViewModels(cfg);
      });

      return config.CreateMapper();
}
```

I splitted each mapping in to method like this:

```
 public IMapperConfigurationExpression MappingModelsToViewModels(IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg)
 {
     cfg = SKU(cfg);
     cfg = Lot(cfg);
     cfg = SalesRate(cfg);
     cfg = SpecialSalesRate(cfg);
     cfg = Order(cfg);
     //...

     return cfg;
}

        public IMapperConfigurationExpression SKU(IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg)
        {
               // HTTPGET
               cfg.CreateMap<SKU, SKUViewModel>() //...
               return cfg; 
        }
```

I ask because I got this error:

> Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate
>   configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a
>   container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the
>   static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or
>   UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the
>   appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.

And I did a test by moving a part of the mapping code in to the new MapperConfiguration and it was working.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways to configure AutoMapper. I *personally* like the following approach -

### Global.ascx.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{   
    ...
    AutoMapperConfiguration.Initialize();
    ...
}
```

### AutoMapperConfiguration.cs

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<SKU, SKUViewModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<SKUViewModel, SKU>();

            cfg.CreateMap<Lot, LotViewModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<LotViewModel, Lot>();
        });
        Mapper = MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
    }

    public static IMapper Mapper { get; private set; }

    public static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration { get; private set; }
}
```

### Usage

Usage will be like -

```
SKUViewModel model = AutoMapperConfiguration.Mapper.Map<SKU, SKUViewModel>(sku);
```

### Unit Test

```
[Test]
public void AutoMapperConfigurationInitializeValid()
{
   AutoMapperConfiguration.Initialize();
   AutoMapperConfiguration.MapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually accomplish this by using the `profile` option `automapper` has. If gives both flexibility and less places to modify later on-

The Profile definition, done by deriving from `AutoMapper` `Profile` class-

```
public class Profile1 : Profile 
{
    public Profile1(){ //... for version < 5, use protected void Configure
         CreateMap<SKU, SKUModel>()
         //........
    }
}
```

Then initialise automapper and load profiles -

```
MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile<Profile1>();
});
Mapper = MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
```

Or you can let `AutoMapper` detect the profiles by itself -

```
// Assembly objects
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfiles(/*.... supply the assembly here ...*/));
```

more can be found here  -

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#profile-instances